# How can I waitFor an element to have children with Geb?

Tags: ajax, spock, geb

I'm executing a test that runs a functional use of a "click to add" feature.
The user is given a table of items that allow them to click an "Add" button to add the item to their cart.

The button executes an ajax call to append the item to the user's cart. When the item is added successfully, the item is then displayed in the Cart UI. The Cart UI is essentially another table.

```
//pseudo code
$('.addButton').on('click', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url:...,
        success: updateCart
    });
});
function updateCart (data) {
    // use data to create tr_fragment
    $("#cart-ui-target").append(tr_fragment); //new row
}
```

What I've tried is in the `then` statement is use waitFor until the `#cart-ui-target` has a `<tr>` size greater or equal to 1:

```
waitFor(5) {$('#cart-ui-target').find('tr').size() >= 1}
```

However, every once in a while the test fails with the following exception:

```
geb.waiting.WaitTimeoutException: condition did not pass in 5.0 seconds (failed with exception)
```

I've even tried to increase the waitFor time to 10 seconds with a 2 second interval, but it still doesn't work:

```
waitFor(10, 2) {$('#cart-ui-target').find('tr').size() >= 1}
```

What can I do to make this a better wait and prevent the sporadic failures?

**UPDATE**
This is what I'm seeing in the log info of phantomjs.

```
$('#cart-ui-target').find('tr').size()
|                  |          |
|                  []         0
[[[[[PhantomJSDriver: phantomjs on LINUX (113358b0-7bf1-11e4-a10e-9f2b2537fa31)] -> tag name: html]] -> css selector: #cart-ui-target]]
```

Comment: When the tests failed due to the `WaitTimeoutException`, did the items actually appear in the specified time or not?

Comment: As far as i can tell they do. The gap in confirmation is the CI system (where the test fails) doesn't handle snapshots well. We're still trying to get that working properly.

Comment: I was able to set the info level for phantomjs; updated question.

Comment: Can you try executing some javascript directly to select the elements instead of using Geb's $() function:

`waitFor{browser.driver.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll('#cart-ui-target tr')").size() > 0}`

Comment: Is there ever an instance where the number of rows is greater than 1 before the test executes? If this is the issue I would get the size of the tr first and test against that. Or better yet wait for the ajax call to finish instead by checking $.active.

Comment: @jk47 Your suggestion seems to be working. I haven't had an issue in the last 4 builds on the CI system.

Comment: @JohnGiotta glad to hear that helped, but why Geb's $() isn't working is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your trying to test the JavaScript behaviour, not the adding to the cart itself (probably tested in backend logic?).

I think the way to go is to mock $.ajax and call the callback from your mock using fixture data. If your using jasmine this can look something this:

```
it('should add something when something is succesfully addes', function() {
  data = 'data_for_callback_here';
  spyOn($, 'ajax').andCallFake(function(data) { data.success(data); } );
  $('.addButton').click();
  expect() // Expect something
});
```

Comment: I am testing JavaScript behavior, but I'm testing with real data. The previous test performs a search which populates table of items.   Then I'm asserting the item "Added" was the same item added to the Cart after the ajax success.

Comment: I don't know your environment but I personally think tests should be isolated. When running a complete integration test things might be different though...

Comment: The integration tests for adding and removing test in isolation. These Geb tests test the user expectations of functionality. These specific tests use a [Stepwise](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/latest/spock/lang/Stepwise.html) order, so functionality of logging in, searching, adding items, removing items, submitting a cart and logging out.